# Filter all files recursively in a directory and then move them to a new set of folders each with a limit of files per directory

Tags: powershell

Sorry for the long title, just trying to be specific.

Here's my scenario today (as the title alludes):

Root Dir has x amount of folders, say 20.  Each folder has files and possible sub-folders.  I know that I only care about the files in any folder with "Hold" in the folder name.

I need to target all files, no matter the type, in the folders and subs.  I then need to move the target files to new folders in the root dir.  Each folder must only house 50,000 files and then roll over to the next folder for the next 50k.  That process will repeat until all the targets have been moved to their new dir.

Here's the PS code I have so far:

```
#SETUP
$FileDir = GCI -Path C:\TEST -Filter 'Hold*' -Directory -Recurse
$FilesinHOLD = GCI -File -Path $FileDir.FullName -Recurse
$NewDir = 'C:\TEST\Limited'
$Limit = '50000'

#Execution
$FilesinHOLD | Select-Object -First $Limit | Move-Item -Destination $NewDir
```

Where I'm left is looking for the mechanism to auto-create a new "Limited" folder and put 50k in there and then repeat the process.  I was wondering if it would be possible to just render the same name simply followed by (2) and then (3) and so on automatically as the default behavior in Windows Explorer..? It would look like this:

> C:\TEST\Limited
>
> C:\TEST\Limited(2)
>
> C:\TEST\Limited(3)

I would finish up by running back through and deleting the now empty "HOLD" directories from which I pulled the files from after verifying they are empty via GCI or Measure-Object.

Thanks in advance for your input.

-CE

Answer (score 1):

Rather than grabbing all the files then removing them from the array, I would move them as I recurse the directories, then loop on that:

```
$rootDir = 'C:\TEST\Limited' 
$NewDir = $rootDir
$Limit = '50000'
$filesMoved = $Limit
$folderCnt = 1
while($filesMoved -ge $limit)
{    
    $filesMoved = GCI -Path C:\TEST -Filter 'Hold*' -Directory -Recurse | GCI -File -Recurse | Select-Object -First $Limit | Move-Item -Destination $NewDir -passthru | measure | select -expand count
    $folderCnt += 1
    $newDir = $rootDir +"($folderCnt)"
}
```

Comment: The above is is not working.  Messed with it a couple times with no luck.  I'm running PS v5 btw

Comment: Move-Item : Access to the path is denied.
At line:8 char:94
+ ... ject -First $Limit | Move-Item -Destination $NewDir -passthru | measu ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\system32\acledit.dll:FileInfo) [Move-Item], Unauthori 
   zedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemComma 
   nd

Comment: zdan, care to take another look?

Comment: @CharlieEcho you don't have permission to move the file `C:\Windows\system32\acledit.dll`

Comment: I'm not trying to move that file. I just copied and pasted your code and thats the error I get.  It should not even be looking at C:\windows as we have not specified that anywhere.  I would love to accept your answer, but its not working for me.

Comment: I didn't realise that '$FileDir' is an array of directories that's probably where the problem is (`$FileDIr.FullName` is empty) . See my edit

Comment: OK, now I got another error.  I think this could be fixed by changing a parameter, but not sure.    Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At line:8 char:126
+ ... ject -First $Limit | Move-Item -Destination $NewDir -passthru | measu ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\TEST\HOLD (3)\test1 - Copy (13).txt:FileInfo) [Move-Item], IOExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: It looks like your source filenames are not unique.

Comment: They are unique, but the behavior I found was that the $NewDir was not a folder, rather an extension-less file named Limited.  Any thoughts?

Comment: '$NewDir` is a string. Which should be fine. Does it fail right away, or does it move a bunch of files first?

Comment: it appears to be failing immediately.  Any chance you would mock this up for a quick test on your end?  I appreciate your help, but at this point I'm feeling like a pest.